# Similar to mail service on website ( Chat system )

Tags: html, database, parse-platform, chat

I'm wanting to create a chat system where user has inboxes so that they can receive, respond, and send messages to one another. It's not going to be a live chat. Rather a mailbox system.

I do know you can achieve this with your database, I just find this as unnecessary data in the far stretch. So is there any other way to fulfill this need of mailbox system? Open for ideas. Thanks :)

PS. I am using the back-end service Parse right now, if that'll help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have to store the messages somewhere. You could discard them after they've been delivered, but I don't think that would be a good user experience. So basically, if you're not going to store them in your database, you're going to have to store them elsewhere. Firebase, DynamoDB a hosted instance of MongoDB or something like that would all be candidates.

You could use all local storage and only keep messages in your database until they're delivered. That seems feasible, but if a user deletes their local storage or loses it for some reason recovery will be an issue.

Comment: Thank you for the response!